# Having a page number in a custom pdf file. (rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I have a rails app in which at one point we have a PDF that is downloaded.  However the problem that i've been having is adding a page number in my footer of my pdf file.  I'm generating the PDF in a file called `report_pdf_service.rb`, essentially what the file does is I am calling a pdf method that calls other methods that are converted into html.

```
def pdf(admin_fields = false)
  html << footer
  html << page_count
  html << '</body></html>'
  PDFKit.new(html).to_pdf
end


def footer
  "".tap do |html|
      html << <<-HTML
      <div>
        <div>Player ID: #{@report.player.id}</div>
        <div>Player Name: #{@report.player.name} </div>
      </div>
    HTML
  end
end
```

Now here is what I have tried.  I've tried working with the PDFKit gem to do this, and have done a little googling, but have not had too much success.  I've tried adding `<meta />{:name => 'pdfkit-footer_right', :content => "[page]"}` within the html. (right below the Player Name entry in the html.....no luck)

I tried creating a new method

```
def page_count
  reader = PDFKit.new(html).to_pdf
  reader.page_count
end
```

....and then calling this in the footer method, yet I keep getting undefined method errors for that method that I tried creating. Would anybody have any idea how this could work?

Answer (score 0):

After a night of working with this issue, I have the solution to this issue.

The solution with how the PDFKit gem works is by adding a meta within the html field.

```
html << %{<meta name='pdfkit-footer_right' content="Page [page] of [toPage]">}
```

I also found this blog which I found to be quite useful as well regarding pdfkits. http://metaskills.net/2011/03/20/pdfkit-overview-and-advanced-usage/